# How can I enable Content-Encoding:gzip to Quarkus HTTP

Tags: gzip, quarkus

I have a file called WebGL.framework.js.gz in resources/META-INF/Build. I want the http serve it with Content-Encoding: gzip. How?

> WebGL.loader.js:1 Unable to parse Build/WebGL.framework.js.gz! This
> can happen if build compression was enabled but web server hosting the
> content was misconfigured to not serve the file with HTTP Response
> Header "Content-Encoding: gzip" present. Check browser Console and
> Devtools Network tab to debug.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/discussions/23162
Please check the link here. It's solved in the GitHub discussions.